# jQuery Actions associated with elements removed and the re-added do not trigger

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_tactic").click(function(){
        var i = ($('#tactic_commentary tr').length-3)/2+1;
        $("#tactic_commentary tr").eq(-1).before('<tr><td style="width: 180px"><div id="form_label">Tactic Name:</div></td><td style="width: 575px" class="auto-style1"><input maxlength="150" name="tactiname'+i+'" style="width: 565px" type="text" /></td></tr>');
        $("#tactic_commentary tr").eq(-1).before('<tr><td style="width: 180px"><div id="form_label" class="auto-style1">Tactic Description:</div></td><td style="width: 575px" class="auto-style1"><textarea name="tacticdescription'+i+'"></textarea></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

My #add_tactic is as follows:

```
<div id="add_tactic">Add Tactic</div>
```

when this page loads, the on click event works fine. If the dropdown in the form changes, it replaces the DIV container with a rebuilt form dependent on your choice.  The on click function of add_tactic does not work when the table is reloaded. Table ID does not change.  Is there something I have to do when removing an element so that events are bound to it when it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove an element all the event handlers bound to it are removed too. Creating a new element, even in the same place with the same id, is exactly that: a new element. You'll need to bind the event handlers again for them to work.

Alternatively, you could bind the handler to a parent container and delegate.

For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '#add_tactic', function(e) {
    // your code here
});
```

This will operate for all instances of #add_tactic now or added at any time in the future. **this** will point to the #add_tactic element

You'd probably want to bind the handler to a container element closer to the #add_tactic element.

Comment: $("tactic_commentary_container").on("click","#add_tactic",(function(){
...   Is a container that never is removed, however It does not trigger the action properly.  before or after removal/return

Comment: Where I've had trouble with delegated handlers it's always been down to some problem on my part in understanding the context I'm executing in. If you can post a simple example (Javascript & HTML) of what you're now doing I could take a look

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. In jQuery we call it event delegation.

You can achieve event delegation by leveraging the use of jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
In short, you need to bind the function to a static element that doesn't get removed/replaced. For this example, we'll use the `document` but for performance, you should target a closer static element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_tactic', function(){
    var i = ($('#tactic_commentary tr').length-3)/2+1;
    $("#tactic_commentary tr").eq(-1).before('<tr><td style="width: 180px"><div id="form_label">Tactic Name:</div></td><td style="width: 575px" class="auto-style1"><input maxlength="150" name="tactiname'+i+'" style="width: 565px" type="text" /></td></tr>');
    $("#tactic_commentary tr").eq(-1).before('<tr><td style="width: 180px"><div id="form_label" class="auto-style1">Tactic Description:</div></td><td style="width: 575px" class="auto-style1"><textarea name="tacticdescription'+i+'"></textarea></td></tr>');
});
```

This will ensure that the click event fires regardless of it being removed/replaced.

Comment: If the element is part of a container that gets overwritten, it would be nontrivial to detach/reattach.  This is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `remove()` or overwrite your html, but rather use the `detach()` method, which will remove the elements from the DOM, but keep the associated data/handlers in jQuery's memory.

```
var detachedHtml = $('#add_tactic').detach();
// later on...
$(parentContainer).append(detachedHtml);
```

Comment: Also a solid alternative to my answer. +1.

Comment: Your alternative is unquestionable cleaner and easier to implement. But...it's generally abused by developers who add a million events to the document.